# C++ '\n' to break a while loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that will echo input chars to the screen using get() and put() until the user presses '\n' '\n' but it breaks with just one '\n'. Thanks for your help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch1, ch2;
    do 
    {    
        cin.get(ch1);
        cout.put(ch1);
        cin.get(ch2);
        cout.put(ch2);
    } while ((ch1 != '\n') && (ch2 != '\n'));
}
```

Comment: It should be `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: Don't you want ((ch1 == '\n') && (ch2 == '\n')) ??

Comment: Thanks so much and to Surt for elaborating.

Comment: @kevinSeleres accept answer if it solves you problem

Answer (score 2):

You should use `||` instead of `&&`

```
int main()
{
char ch1, ch2;
do 
{    
cin.get(ch1);
cout.put(ch1);
cin.get(ch2);
cout.put(ch2);
} while ((ch1 != '\n') || (ch2 != '\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have turned your logic around.

```
} while ((ch1 != '\n') && (ch2 != '\n'));
```

your here saying which i don't have a '\n' and and not have a '\n' but you do have a '\n' so the first part is false and then the second clause is irrelevant as C++ short-circuit evaluation of || && expressions.

ie.

```
false && something
```

is always false.

Answer (score 0):

Try using | | instead of &&.